# Post image to like page wall using Facebook API for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to post an image to like page wall using facebook api in iPhone. I tried to post using graph api, but only the message is appearing on the page wall but no image. Any one can help me out for this issue please.. I dont want to post to a like page which i owns but the page i liked..

Thanks in advance

Augustine P A

Answer (score 0):

use this with your own image

```
NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[args setObject:@"message" forKey:@"caption"];
[args setObject:@"message" forKey:@"message"];
[args setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenshotIMG1, 0.7) forKey:@"picture"];
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
               andParams:args
           andHttpMethod:@"POST"
             andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But i am getting an error message like this
    error_msg=Unknown method, error_code=3

I made a call as given

   [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"443136362369295/photos.upload"
                              andParams:args
                          andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                            andDelegate:self];

443136362369295 is page ID. Please let me know what mistake i made...